# is this the right way to delete object inside dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

i wrote a class inheriting from dict, i wrote a member method to remove objects.

```
class RoleCOList(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        dict.__init__(self)

    def recyle(self):
        '''
        remove roles too long no access
        '''
        checkTime = time.time()-60*30
        l = [k for k,v in self.items() if v.lastAccess>checkTime]
        for x in l:
            self.pop(x)
```

isn't it too inefficient? i used 2 list loops but i couldn't find other way

Comment: its one way ... you could also just call `del l[x]` which would probably be faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the SciPy conference last year, I attended a talk where the speaker said that `any()` and `all()` are fast ways to do a task in a loop.  It makes sense; a `for` loop rebinds the loop variable on each iteration, whereas `any()` and `all()` simply consume the value.

Clearly, you use `any()` when you want to run a function that always returns a false value such as `None`.  That way, the whole loop will run to the end.

```
checkTime = time.time() - 60*30

# use any() as a fast way to run a loop
# The .__delitem__() method always returns `None`, so this runs the whole loop
lst = [k for k in self.keys() if self[k].lastAccess > checkTime]
any(self.__delitem__(k) for k in lst)
```

Comment: hmm,maybe this is by far the best answer,use loop inside a built-in function would get better performance.

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

```
_ = [self.pop(k) for k,v in self.items() if v.lastAccess>checkTime]
```

Comment: The `_ =` doesn't help and may hurt, since it stops the popped items from being reference counted out of existence until the `_` goes out of scope.

Comment: true, if you expect the dicts to be very large then don't use it

Comment: you can't do this while iteration.or it will give you an error:RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: are you sure? I tested it with a dummy dict

Comment: @Max He's probably on Python 2 where `items` creates a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need the list you generated, you could use generators and a snippet from this [consume recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes). In particular, use `collections.deque` to run through a generator for you.

```
checkTime = time.time()-60*30

# Create a generator for all the values you will age off
age_off = (self.pop(k) for k in self.keys() if self[k].lastAccess>checkTime)

# Let deque handle iteration (in one shot, with little memory footprint)
collections.deque(age_off,maxlen=0)
```

Since the dictionary is changed during the iteration of age_off, use `self.keys()` which returns a list. (Using `self.iteritems()` will raise a `RuntimeError`.)

Comment: you can't do this while iteration.or it will give you an error:RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: At least for me, the RuntimeError only comes up when using self.iteritems(). Since I'm sneaky, I did change the code to reflect that earlier. ;)

Answer (score 0):

My (completly unreadable solution):

```
from operator import delitem
map(lambda k: delitem(self,k), filter(lambda k: self[k].lastAccess<checkTime, iter(self)))
```

but at least it should be quite time and memory efficient ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If performance is an issue, and if you will have large volumes of data, you might want to look into using a Python front-end for a system like memcached or redis; those can handle expiring old data for you.

http://memcached.org/

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-memcached/

http://redis.io/

https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py